# ASP select option, if else syntax

Tags: asp-classic

How to add extra attribute use if else statement in ASP?  I have a list as shown below.

```
<select>
<option value="100">$100</option>
<option value="200">$200</option>
<option value="300">$300</option>
</select>
```

How can I write like this way using asp,

```
if (num = 100){
  add attr selected="selected" to <option value="100">
   //read as <option value="100" selected="selected"$100</option>
}if (num = 200){
  add attr selected="selected" to <option value="200">
   //read as <option value="200" selected="selected"$200</option>
}else{
   add attr selected="selected" to <option value="300">
   //read as <option value="300" selected="selected"$300</option>
}
```

I don't really know ASP syntax, only know PHP!

Thanks

Comment: u sure you don't want to to it in JS?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I have done it in JS, but required it by ASP! thanks

Comment: And this is classic ASP/VBScript, *not* ASP.NET? Just to confirm

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - from the look of it, it could be ASP/JScript - but I would also like some confirmation of ASP-Classic or ASP.Net. Seems to be a small but regular stream of people adding the wrong tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *classic* ASP you could do something like:

```
<% 
   Dim num
   num = 200
%>

<select>
   <option value="100" <% If num = 100 Then Response.Write "selected='selected'" %>>$100</option>
   <option value="200" <% If num = 200 Then Response.Write "selected='selected'" %>>$200</option>
   <option value="300" <% If num <> 100 And num <> 200 Then Response.Write "selected='selected'" %>>$300</option>
</select>
```